# How do I force Time Machine to use a sparsebundle?

Tags: backup, time-machine, sparsebundle

I have previously used a sparsebundle for my Time Machine backups by creating an image in an existing APFS volume that is local to my iMac (it's RAID), not a NAS or anything of that sort.

For reasons I won't go into, I had to delete the Time Machine sparsebundle so thought I might as well use the RAID volume directly to store the sparsebundle, rather than creating an image within a volume.

It seems that macOS will only create a sparsebundle if the drive is not local. I would like to create a sparsebundle because I am storing my Time Machine backups on the cloud, Google Drive in particular.

Is it possible to configure Time Machine to create a sparsebundle, even for local drives? If not, I will have to revert to using a manually-created image. The Time Machine drive is APFS (Case-sensitive, Encrypted).

Comment: What version of macOS?

Comment: The latest version, 11.4